# How to solve "No such file or directory" problem in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to read a csv file after installing a package called plotnine

`import plotnine as p9`

`mtcars = pd.read_csv("mtcars2.csv")`

but I got the error:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mtcars2.csv'`.

I thought the file is already contained in the package, but not so sure now.
I was wondering if there is a recommended way to fix this problem.

Comment: provide the exact path of the input file..

Comment: I just copied someone's code and thought the file is contained in the package called `plotnine`. But now I am not sure that due to the error. So you think the file is probably in his working directory then?

Comment: Here's a file with that name: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rsquaredacademy-education/datasets/master/mtcars2.csv

Comment: probably. You would have to create your own file with that name, and then put it in the same directory as your python file.